# Why in next.js " use client " in top of component give me this error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

when i  use "use client" in the top of my component i get this error:

```
event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.5s (265 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 932 ms (265 modules)
wait  - compiling /page (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.5s (531 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1131 ms (531 modules)
error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
wait  - compiling /favicon.ico/route (client and server)...
event - compiled successfully in 455 ms (300 modules)`
```

For this code:

```json
`      "dependencies": {
        "eslint": "8.38.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "13.3.0",
        "next": "13.3.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "18.2.0"
      }`
```

```js
'use client'
export default function Home() {
  console.log("====================================");
  console.log("Test");
  console.log("====================================");
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Next.js</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried to use `client-side-render` and I also had an error

Comment: It doesn't seem related to `'use client '`. More like you parse `undefined` somewhere

Comment: This is due to nextjs 13.3 version. You steps mentioned. I also face same issue. 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9sGfWSrSlvc

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, you can not set `"use client"` directive alongside `export default function F () {}`, but with `const F = () => {}; export default F` instead. It's weird, but this workaround worked for me. Good luck!

```js
"use client"

const Home = () => {
  console.log("====================================");
  console.log("Test");
  console.log("====================================");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Next.js</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```